# Which events to trap on taphold

Tags: jquery-mobile

I listen for the taphold event on an element and then open a popup with choices of actions. The problem is, after the popup is opened, new mouse/finger events are triggered. So my solution is to trap all the subsequent mouse/finger events until the touchend event:

```
function tapholdTriggered() {

    $.mcm.mobile.$d.on('vclick.taphold vmousedown.taphold click.taphold mousedown.taphold tap.taphold taphold.taphold touchstart.taphold touchmove.taphold', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    })
                   .on('touchend.taphold', function (event) {

                       event.preventDefault();
                       event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                       $.mcm.mobile.$d.off('.taphold');

                   });

}
```

So basically I would listen for the taphold event, call tapholdTriggered(), then open the popup.

My question/issue is that I think I am excessively trapping events. I don't know what order the various mouse/finger events are fired in. So if someone could help me optimize the trapped events, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Ws853/

Comment: This one is what I am trying to do. It works, but like I said, I'm probably going overboard on the trapped events since I don't know the order: http://jsfiddle.net/Ws853/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this a little differently using a screen that covers the body and then gets removed on touchend, mouseup, and vmouseup.